# Not able to pass Multiple image to Server Nodejs

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, retrofit2, multer

I have created an application using an android studio and for server-side using NodeJs.I have tried to pass a single image and able to pass. This time, I want to pass multiple images to the server, but when I started change parameter from `image:MultipleBody.Part` to `images:List<MultipartBody.Part>` at Api.kt file, received an error message at the server-side. I don't know with a part that I'm doing it wrong. Hope can help me solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

> $ node app Listening on port 4545... MulterError: Unexpected field
>       at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
>       at Busboy. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
>       at Busboy.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
>       at PartStream. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
>       at PartStream.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at HeaderParser. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
>       at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
>       at SBMH. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)
>   MulterError: Unexpected field
>       at wrappedFileFilter (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\multer\index.js:40:19)
>       at Busboy. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:114:7)
>       at Busboy.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at Busboy.emit (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\busboy\lib\main.js:38:33)
>       at PartStream. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\busboy\lib\types\multipart.js:213:13)
>       at PartStream.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at HeaderParser. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\dicer\lib\Dicer.js:51:16)
>       at HeaderParser.emit (events.js:223:5)
>       at HeaderParser._finish (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:68:8)
>       at SBMH. (C:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\EIS-API\node_modules\dicer\lib\HeaderParser.js:40:12)

**Api.kt**

```
  @Multipart
    @POST("perkhidmatan_rumput/api/PostPemantauanPerkhidmatanPotingRumput" +
            "/{zon}/{syarikat}/{alamat_syarikat}/{nama_penyelia}/{taman}/{bulan}/{tahun}" +
            "/{masa}/{timeAMPM}/{pusingan}/{status}/{catatan}/{state}/{entryOperator}")
    fun  postPemantauanPerkhidmatanPotingRumput(
        @Path("zon")zon:String,
        @Path("syarikat")syarikat:String,
        @Path("alamat_syarikat")alamat_syarikat:String,
        @Path("nama_penyelia")nama_penyelia:String,
        @Path("taman")taman:Int,
        @Path("bulan")bulan:String,
        @Path("tahun")tahun:String,
        @Path("masa")masa:String,
        @Path("timeAMPM")timeAMPM:String,
        @Path("pusingan")pusingan:String,
        @Path("status")status:String,
        @Path("catatan")catatan:String,
        @Path("state")state:String,
        @Path("entryOperator")entryOperator:String,
        @Part images:List<MultipartBody.Part>
        //@Part image:MultipartBody.Part?

    ):LiveData<GenericApiResponse<OnResponse>>
```

PemoViewModel.kt

```
public fun  getAllImages():List<MultipartBody.Part>?{
    var info = getCurrentViewStateOrNew()
    var pic:List<GambarSebelum>? = info.gambarSebelum
    var images = mutableListOf<MultipartBody.Part>()
    pic?.let {

       for ( item in it){

           var multipartBody: MultipartBody.Part? = null

           item.url?.path?.let { filePath ->
               val imageFile = File(filePath)

               val requestBody =
                   RequestBody.create(
                       MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                       imageFile
                   )

               multipartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                   "image",
                   imageFile.name,
                   requestBody
               )
           }

           images.add(multipartBody!!);
       }


    }

    return images;

}
```

PemoFragment.kt

```
  _binding.btnLogin.setOnClickListener {
            if(!isFill()){
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"sila penuhkan ruang diatas..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

            var bulan:String = CALENDER.valueOf(_binding.idBulanSpinner.selectedItem.toString()).value
            var taman:Int? = _viewModel.getTamanIdByTamanName(_binding.idTamanSpinner.selectedItem.toString())
            var pusingan:String? = _viewModel.getPusinganByPusinganName(_binding.idPusinganSpinner.selectedItem.toString())
            var status:String? = _viewModel.getStatusByStatusName(_binding.idStatusSpinner.selectedItem.toString())
            var images:List<MultipartBody.Part>? = _viewModel.getAllImages()

            if(taman != null && pusingan != null && status != null){



                //insert information to server (database)
                _viewModel.setStateEvent(
                    FormRumputStateEvent.SubmitPemantauanForm(
                        PemantauanPotongRumputResponse(
                            _binding.idZonsSpinner.selectedItem.toString(),
                            _binding.idNamaSyarikatEdit.text.toString(),
                            _binding.idAlamatSyarikat.text.toString(),
                            _binding.idNamaPenyeliaKontraktorEdit.text.toString(),
                            taman,
                            bulan,
                            _binding.idTahunEdit.text.toString(),
                            _binding.idMasaEdit.text.toString(),
                            _binding.idAmPmSpinner.selectedItem.toString(),
                            pusingan,
                            status,
                            _binding.idCatatanEdit.text.toString(),
                            STATE_STATUS.CREATE.name,
                            "ADMIN",
                            images!!
                        )
                    ))
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"[Error] Taman,Bulan,pusingan or status has Problem..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                return@setOnClickListener
            }

        }
```

**PemantauanPotongRumputResponse**

```
data class PemantauanPotongRumputResponse(
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("zon")
    val zon:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("syarikat")
    val syarikat:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("alamat_syarikat")
    val alamat_syarikat:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("nama_penyelia")
    val nama_penyelia:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("taman")
    val taman:Int,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("bulan")
    val bulan:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("tahun")
    val tahun:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("masa")
    val masa:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("timeAMPM")
    val timeAMPM:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("pusingan")
    val pusingan:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("status")
    val status:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("catatan")
    val catatan:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("state")
    val state:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("entryOperator")
    val entryOperator:String,
    @Expose
    @SerializedName("images")
    val images:List<MultipartBody.Part>

)
```

**SERVER SIDE**
**NODE.JS**

```
router.post('/api/PostPemantauanPerkhidmatanPotingRumput/:zon/:syarikat/:alamat_syarikat/'+
          ':nama_penyelia/:taman/:bulan/:tahun/:masa/:timeAMPM/:pusingan/:status/:catatan/:state/'+
          ':entryOperator', upload.array('images',9),(req,res,next) =>{

               try{
                    const file = req.files;
                    if (!file) {
                        res.status(400).json({
                            "status": "failed",
                            "code" : "400",
                            "message" : "Please upload file"
                        });
                    }

                    res.status(200).json({
                        "status": "success",
                        "code" : "200",
                        "message" : "file uploaded successfully"
                    });
                    console.log(file);
                    console.log(req.body);
                }catch(err){
                    console.log(error.message);
                    res.status(200).json({
                        "status": "failed",
                        "code" : "500",
                        "message" : error.message
                    });
                }


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Able to Solved the problem. Just make sure the first parameter "images" at `MultipartBody.Part.createFormData` same at Server-Side parameter `upload.array("images")`

```
multipartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                   "images",
                   imageFile.name,
                   requestBody
               )
```

**PemoViewMode.kt**

```
public fun  getAllImages():List<MultipartBody.Part>?{
    var info = getCurrentViewStateOrNew()
    var pic:List<GambarSebelum>? = info.gambarSebelum
    var images = mutableListOf<MultipartBody.Part>()
    pic?.let {
       for ( item in it){
           var multipartBody: MultipartBody.Part? = null
           item.url?.path?.let { filePath ->
               val imageFile = File(filePath)
               val requestBody =
                   RequestBody.create(
                       MediaType.parse("image/*"),
                       imageFile
                   )
               multipartBody = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(
                   "images",
                   imageFile.name,
                   requestBody
               )
           }
           images.add(multipartBody!!);
       }
    }
    return images;
}
```

**SERVER-SIDE (NODEJS)**

```
router.post('/api/PostPemantauanPerkhidmatanPotingRumput/:zon/:syarikat/:alamat_syarikat/'+
          ':nama_penyelia/:taman/:bulan/:tahun/:masa/:timeAMPM/:pusingan/:status/:catatan/:state/'+
          ':entryOperator', upload.array('images',9),(req,res,next) =>{

               try{
                    const file = req.files;
                    if (!file) {
                        res.status(400).json({
                            "status": "failed",
                            "code" : "400",
                            "message" : "Please upload file"
                        });
                    }

                    res.status(200).json({
                        "status": "success",
                        "code" : "200",
                        "message" : "file uploaded successfully"
                    });
                    console.log(file);
                    console.log(req.body);
                }catch(err){
                    console.log(error.message);
                    res.status(200).json({
                        "status": "failed",
                        "code" : "500",
                        "message" : error.message
                    });
                }


})
```